# Looking for a collaborative document management system with version control and tagging

Tags: collaboration, document-management

I am one of the organizers of the National Math Olympiad here in my country. We basically create a bunch of math problems, and then select a subset of them to design a couple of contest rounds.

### The setup

We would like to use some software/add-on to make our workflow as smooth as possible. The following is a somewhat ideal life cycle of a problem.

1. Each member of the team works on drafts for the statement of a couple of problems, together with the solutions for them.
2. At least two other members of the team read each problem and make suggestions/changes/corrections.
3. After the changes have been discussed, the author or an admin promotes the problem from draft to a pool of problems that are ready to be selected for a contest.
4. When we hit a deadline, we stop making drafts and focus on selecting from the pool to build a series of tests. We must make in total 9 tests, in increasing order of difficulty, and with a mix of subjects (a test with 5 problems can't have 4 geometry questions).

This way, we can reuse problems from past years, both from the draft folder and also from the polished folder.

### Our current method

We are working on plain Google Drive, having a folder for the drafts, another for the polished problems, and a final one for the accepted problems for the contest.

What we value about the current method is that we are able to comment on other people's work and also suggest with little to no effort and in real-time. It is also possible to have LaTeX support for math equations, all of that for free.

What we don't like about the current workflow is that:

1. We are not able to assign tags to problems on the free version of Google Drive. That way, we must manually record how diverse the set of problems is (as opposed to having a green tag called "geometry" which tells you how much geometry you need to balance your mix of topics). We currently have a metadocument listing every problem and its tags.
2. Also, it is annoying to manually have to move one document from one folder to another whenever one problem changes its status. Having a less strict way of differentiating file status would solve this issue.

I have previously used Jira for task management, and I found interesting and smooth the concept of staging an issue from one column to another, and also the fact that you can assign multiple tags to one issue (such as difficulty level, main topic, and author). However, I feel that the text formatting Jira provides won't be enough for a problem statement, let alone its solution, which could take up a couple of pages and may need images.

Also, it is not clear to me how we could make suggestions as smoothly as in Google Drive. Yes, you can make comments, but they seem to add friction to the conversation.

We could just create a task on Jira as if it were a problem, tag it and add a link to the google docs. But the link seems superficial, only working one way: When you are on a google document, you are not able to see the current tasks for the problem, nor in which stage of the process is it.

Is any set of apps recommended for our purposes?

Comment: Were you able to find a recommendation?

Comment: No, but if your project is not that big, you could use a notion template to cover some of the problems addressed in this post (notion has a 1000 cell limit on their free version)